# How is integer literal mapped in memory?

Tags: c

Take a look at the following example:

```
int a = 130;
char *ptr;
ptr = (char *) &a;
printf("%d", *ptr);
```

I expected to get a value `0` printed on the screen but to my surprise it's `-126`. I came to the conclusion that since `char` is 8 bits the `int` might be rounding.

Until now I used to think that memory is filled in a way that msb is on the left. But now everything seems to be mixed. How exactly is memory allocated?

Comment: Most computers today are ["little endian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_endian), with the MSB notionally at the *right*.

Comment: @SteveSummit So it's reverse of how we write on paper?

Comment: @BhaiJaan Sure is.  Definitely confusing at first, but it ends up having some real advantages.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thankyou steve, I'll check the advantages.

Comment: Try this: `int i = 16909060; unsigned char *p = &i; printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case `a` (might be) 4 bytes [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) value. and 130 is 10000010  in binary.

```c
int a = 130; // 10000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 see little endianness here
```

and you're pointing to the first byte with `char*`

```c
char* ptr = (char*)&a; // 10000010
```

and trying to print it with `%d` format which will print the signed integer value of `10000010` which is `-126` (see: [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement))

Comment: It's like everybody knows about it except me :D

Comment: @adder from left to right the address is increasing and LSB is stored in the lowest address

Answer (score 0):

Your output is a hint that your system is little endian (Least Significant Byte has lowest memory address).

In hexadecimal (exactly 2 digit per byte) 130 writes 0x82. Assuming 4 bytes for an int, in a little endian system, the integer will be stored as 0x82, 0, 0, 0. So `*ptr` will be `(char) 0x82`.

But you use `printf` to display its value. As all parameters passed the first have no required type, the char value will be promoted to an int. Here assuming a 2 complement representation (the currently most common one) you will get either 130 if `char` was unsigned, or -126 if is is signed.

TL/DR: the output is normal on a little endian system with a 2-complement integer representation, and where the `char` type is signed.